# Unable to recover from an exception in tornado_sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I'm using `tornado_sqlalchemy` to manage my sessions, this is due to many issues I had when running regular `sqlalchemy` myself which I had to manage.

I load my Tornado server like so:

```py
app = tornado.web.Application(
         ...
         db=SQLAlchemy(url=get_db_url(),
                       engine_options={
                         "pool_pre_ping": True,
                         "execution_options": {
                            "isolation_level": "AUTOCOMMIT"
                         }
                       }
    )
```

Then, I defined pages like so:

```py
from tornado_sqlalchemy import SessionMixin

class MyPage(tornado.web.RequestHandler, SessionMixin):
  # Run things in the background
  executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

  def render_myhtml(self):
    # self.session generate a unique session for this class by SessionMixin automatically
    results = self.session.query(...)
```

All issues were gone, but now I face a different issue.
Let's say one of the web pages is running a heavy query in the backend, I run it like so:

```py
@run_on_executor
def get_query_results(self):
  ...
```

And I open the website - 12 times ( = 12 tabs ) to check how it handles the load.
result is:

```
X tabs      - works fine ( the number of X changes )
12 - x tabs - result with 500 internal server error.
```

500 error, the backend displays stuff like:

```py
# One tab received and crashed, which started a chain of other errors
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')

# Other tab afterwards received and crashed:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

# Other tab afterwards received and crashed:
pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 102 expected 3

# Other tab received:
sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/8s2b)
```

And now:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30.00 (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/3o7r)
```

My issue is - that after Tornado encounters an error - it doesn't "release" or recover those sessions.
Any page that I'll try to load from now until I restart the Tornado server - will simply hang until the resulting 500 internal error.

To reproduce, we can set up the following in the `engine_options`:

```py
pool_size = 2
max_overflow = 0
```

And open 3 tabs at once.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this issue and recover those sessions or throw them away?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should open session (and close) in each user's request
2. You can increase `pool_size` to be satisfied. But only if your database allows

Also, I recommend you to use [SqlAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/) package in next way.

engine:

```
engine = asa.create_async_engine(
    self.app_context.db_config.db_async_con_string,
    echo=False,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    pool_size=self.app_context.db_config.pool_size,
    max_overflow=self.app_context.db_config.max_overflow,
)
```

and session:

```
session = sessionmaker(
    engine,
    expire_on_commit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    class_=asa.AsyncSession
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the `Async` example, it's good to know. but in anyway, see my header: `class MyPage(tornado.web.RequestHandler, SessionMixin):` i'm using `SessionMixin` which just gives `self.session` to be available, so I never "open"/"create" the connection, and i never "close" it ...